# Create dynamic modal with angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I display the list of groups in one page, if user clicks on the name of the group, a modal contains the informations of the group is displayed.

The problem is that all modal always displays informations of the first group.
I know there is module do this functionality but how I can do it only through angular2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: I found the solution. the solution is to pass dynamically variable to “data-target=” to create multiple modal, I hope my solution help others people.

Answer (score 0):

You component's template lists all your groups

```
 <group (click)="openModal('groupName1')></group>
 <group (click)="openModal('groupName2')></group>
 ...
```

Then in you component add a method like this

```
openModal(name) {
NgbdModalContent.name = name;
this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
}
```

Comment: modal always displays informations of the first group